# Intel NUC10i7FNH shuts down after selecting Ubuntu in GNU GRUB version 2.04

Tags: boot, grub2, shutdown

I'm a newbie to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS on my NUC10i7FNH and it seemed to go well (https://itsfoss.com/install-linux-on-intel-nuc/).

When the NUC reboots it shows a GNU GRUB version 2.04 menu with three options - Ubuntu, Unbuntu (other options), Bios (I think).

If I select the 'Ubuntu' option the NUC shuts down after about 2 seconds and the following message is briefly displayed:
/dev/nvme0n1p2: recovering journal

/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 200444/61022208 files, ....

If I select 'Ubuntu (other options)' screeds of text scroll by in about 3 seconds and then the NUC shuts down.

I've updated the BIOS, and I've ordered a new power supply.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 200444/61022208 files, ....  Hard drive problem bad drive, drive going bad or bad install. I would reinstall. I've updated the BIOS, and I've ordered a new power supply. Why nothing you put in the question says you need to do this.

Comment: ".... and I've ordered a new power supply" Yes, sorry that was a bit random. I read on some other thread that a bad power supply might be the cause of unexpected shutdowns and so I figured that that's a cheap/quick avenue to explore. I bought the NUC on eBay without the power supply and so I bought one on Amazon ... and I'm now questioning whether that's the issue.

Comment: @David - I got the new power supply today and my NUC booted right into Ubuntu and I'm up and running! After playing around for a while I then shutdown and re-tried my original power supply - Ubuntu booted up again, but when I tried to run an app it shut down. So the issue was the power supply after all.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the power supply and my NUC booted up without issue.